# Mitochondrial shape and function

Tags: cell-biology, mitochondria

I was wondering how can mitochondria come in different shapes and sizes? And why are they always shown as ovals on textbooks?

p.s. I would appreciate any suggestions for wider reading on mitochondria and cellular biology as well.

Comment: Welcome laerningsheep. Please take our [tour] and read-up in the [help], especially the [ask] section, taking particular note of the requirement that questions should show their prior research. You can then [edit] to show us what you searched, found and where you got stuck. Perhaps start with [Mitochondrial evolution](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3428767/) to get an idea about where we think they come from at present.